# jQuery plugin works with version 1.6.4 but does not with 1.8.2

Tags: jquery, version

I am trying to use a jQuery scrollbar plugin (this one: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ScrollbarVisibility/) and I have noticed two things:

1. This plugin works perfectly under Google Chrome(or Chromium) and Firefox (or Iceweasel) when the version of jQuery is 1.6.4.
2. The plugin works fine under Google Chrome but NOT under Firefox when I use jQuery version 1.8.2.

Can any one give me an explanation of this, because I am rather surprised!

Right now I am using 1.6.4 with a little script that removes event.layerX and layerY which are deprecated.

Thank you ;)

Comment: check your JS error console. probably something got changed/updated in 1.8 that the plugin can't handle.

Comment: Please update the respective plugins to their latest versions and try again. The version of jscrollpane in the given demo is from 2011.

Comment: Which version of plugin is used? It [looks like](https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane) support of jQuery 1.8 has been added just a month ago.

Comment: I think I'm using an old ersion of the plugin. I didn't notice until now. Nevertheless, I jus tried with the last one and it doesn't really work, though (it's quite worst in fact... It just doesn't work at all).

Thank you any way!